# rails --- what is the value of object after destroy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a newbie to RoR. I want to know what will be the value of **object** (particularly, **instance variable**) after destroy in the controller.

For example in the following code, what will be the value of **@cart** object (instance variable) after invoking the destroy method in the controller.

```
#app/controllers/carts_controller.rb
def destroy
    @cart.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to store_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
end
```

In addition, I use this **@cart** object in the view(.html.erb file) to show the list of shopping items. How this **@cart** object is gonna be happened in this view after destroy.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends in a lot of things.

The short answer is that `@cart` remains unmodified after the `.destroy` method call.

The long answer is that can be a bunch of`callbacks` invoked by *ActiveRecord* or by your own implementation, including the destruction of all the related elements to this `cart` element. Also the record in the DB has been removed so if you are trying to load a relation, as relations are normally *lazy* loaded, this relation can be empty if you load it after the destruction of the parent element.

So I recommend to load all the elements that are gonna be used in your view before you destroy the parent one.

Answer (score 0):

`@cart` in your example refers to a particular instance of the `Cart` model.

The way you've outlined it here, I'm assuming that you're using Rails 4 because the code that actually sets `@cart` is not in your `destroy` method

What happens when the `DELETE` request comes in via HTTP, Rails goes to your data store and returns a copy bound to `@cart`, when `.destroy` is called the original item from the data store is destroyed and @cart would then become `Nil`

`@cart` used elsewhere should not be affected because each instance related to the data in the data store

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: thanks for answer, but I'm not very sure about @cart would become Nil.